# How can I react on Mouse events in a Java applet and then paint accordingly?

Tags: java, applet

My homework is

> Write an applet that draw the house shown on the left in Figure 14-32. When the user clicks on the door or windows, they should close. The figure on the right shows the house with its door and windows closed.

I basically want a Java Applet where, if a user clicks on a rectangle, another one is sudden created and drawn.

Here is my code so far.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test2 extends JApplet
{
    private final int currentX = 0;


    public void init()
    {
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    }

    public void paint (final Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint (g);

        g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    }

    private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {

        currentX = e.getX();
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is? "Dear Stackoverflow, please do my homework for me"?

Comment: What’s the problem? You already have code, so … What?

Comment: where is the house? Please tag these questions as homework.

Comment: The problem is how do you create if statement that allows a action listener. I want to  allow a user to make a if statement that they selects a component an action happens. I don't know were to find the answer.

Comment: The problem is how do you create if statement that allows a action listener. I want to  allow a user to make a if statement that they selects a component an action happens. I don't know were to find the answer. for example if (frame,isSelected()) draw.rect                    my problem is i don't know how to do this with a applet or action handler.

Comment: @user: please edit your question to add the problem description. Don't just post it as a comment.

Comment: @userNNNN "My homework is - Write an applet..".  Do me a favor, will you?  Find the person who specified this homework, smack them upside the head & tell them NEVER to get newbies to do applet development again.  Applets are a PITA, and much more complicated to develop, debug and deploy than standard (JFrame based) GUI projects.  For more details see (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) - which (admittedly) was written by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Java Tutorial | How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). It will help you determine when and where a user clicks. Once you have these (x,y) coordinates you can check if they lie within the window or the door and if so, draw something else.

Sample code:

```
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       int x = e.getX();
       int y = e.getY();

       //check if (x,y) lie in a certain rectangle
       if(x>100 && x<300 && y>100 && y<300){
           //set a variable and repaint
           closeDoors = true;
           repaint();
       }
   }
```

In your paint method, you need to check if the `closeDoors` variable is set and if so, draw something else.

```
public void paint (final Graphics g){
    super.paint (g);
    g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    if(closeDoors){
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you put a action listener into a if statement?. I can't use the mouse click method

Answer (score 0):

**When the user clicks on the door or windows**, then you check if the mouse coordinates are inside the window or door area and, if yes, you replace the drawing of an open door or open window by a drawing of a closed one, which then will look like: **they should close**.

So, that's what you have to do:

- the "house" model consists of a building, a door and a window, each represented by coordinates
- "door" and "window" can be painted either in "open" or "close" mode
- You need *test* method to check, if a mouse click occured "on" the windoww or "on" the door

*Tip*: your current implementation of MouseListener doesn't work at all. You have to override methods from `MouseAdapter` and put your *test* in the appropriate method.